# Presto SQL date_format extract week of year

Tags: sql, presto

Documentation : https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

I have epoch timestamps from which I want to extract week of the year like `2021-32`, `2020-50`, `2021-02` and so on.

```
SELECT concat(date_format(from_unixtime((CAST(my_timestamp AS BIGINT) + 19800000)/1000), '%Y'), 
            '-' ,
            date_format(from_unixtime((CAST(my_timestamp AS BIGINT) + 19800000)/1000), '%v')) 
AS week
```

However I am getting up some wrong values like :
week = `2021-53` for Epoch-Time corresponding to Jan 1, 2021 or Jan 2, 2021. I understand that there is a sync issue happening here but that is definitely not something I want - How do I offset so that first day of week 1 starts from the beginning of the year.

Comment: If 53 looks too high, then you could start with week 00?  `date_format(date('2021-01-03'), '%Y-%u')` (Sunday) returns 2021-00

Comment: @LukStorms Strangely I get an error that %u is not supported as a format, even though I see it listed on the docs.    
`INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: %u not supported in date format string` .    
I am running queries on AWS Athena which uses Presto SQL engine underneath.

Comment: My bad. There's a warning in the documentation. `The following specifiers are not currently supported: %D %U %u %V %w %X`  Oh well, probably not many would need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it using `week_of_year` and `year_of_week` methods.
Docs : https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#week

Query :

```
SELECT concat(CAST(year_of_week(from_unixtime((CAST(my_timestamp AS BIGINT) + 19800000)/1000)) AS varchar(15)),
              '-',
              CAST(week_of_year(from_unixtime((CAST(my_timestamp AS BIGINT) + 19800000)/1000)) AS varchar(15))) as week
```

Had to introduce some extra casts to varchar since concat doesn't support multiple datatypes.

**Edit** :
Another issue with above solution is that `week_of_year` returns single-digit weeks like `1`, `2` instead of `01`, `02` - thus causing an issue while sorting with these week numbers.

I ended up using a combination of `year_of_week` to get the correct year, and the general `date_format(date, '%v')` for week-numbers.

**Updated Query :**

```
SELECT concat(CAST(year_of_week(from_unixtime((CAST(my_timestamp AS BIGINT) + 19800000)/1000)) AS varchar(15)),
              '-',
              date_format(from_unixtime((CAST(my_timestamp AS BIGINT) + 19800000)/1000), '%v'))
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case you should just get the count of days and calculate the week.
Something like this:

```
SELECT concat(date_format(from_unixtime((CAST(my_timestamp AS BIGINT) + 19800000)/1000), '%Y'), 
            '-' ,
            ceiling(date_format(from_unixtime((CAST(my_timestamp AS BIGINT) + 19800000)/1000), '%j')/7)) 
AS week
```

Comment: While this might work, it needed me to add multiple casts -> First to `int` in order to support division by 7, and then re-cast that to varchar to support concat.       
Plus division by 7 seems like a hack to me. I found a native support for this, please check my answer - would like to hear your opinion on it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sync issue here - it expected behaviour for [`date_format`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions) and it's MySQL [counterpart](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear).

Note, that you can use full format string on the date:

```sql
select date_format(timestamp '2021-01-01', '%Y-%v')
```

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2021-53 |

You can try calculating week number by dividing `day_of_year` by 7:

```sql
select ceiling(day_of_year(timestamp '2021-01-01') / 7.0)
```

Related:

- presto [github issue](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/12167)
- joda [weekOfWeekyear docs](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/field.html#weekOfWeekyear)